# Rails: Where to define a helper method that will be available to several controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to define a helper method, `my_method`, that will be available inside `BuyersController` methods (like `index`, `create`, e.t.c.).

I tried to define it in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` but it didn't work:

```
undefined method `my_method' for #<BuyersController:0x26df468>
```

It should be in some shared place because I want to use it in other controllers also. This is why I tried `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`.

What is the right place to define it ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should be in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

The `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` is for shared *view* helpers.

Comment: I think Misha is asking for methods available to controllers **and** views. A method in `ApplicationController` will be available to all controllers but not to their views.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't interested in methods for views.

Comment: For completeness, in a modern Rails version, define a controller method `foo` as a view helper with `helper_method :foo` in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

You should include the application helper module in your application controller so that its methods will be available everywhere (all controllers and views) during a request.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper ApplicationHelper
  …
end
```

See the API docs for the [helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper) method

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Rails 3 you could also call `view_context.my_method` inside your controller

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4734403/2001785), if you *did* want to share a controller method with views, [`helper_method`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8d7cf75684d5e76ef635f92125a51cb4c1c0fd3b/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb#L60) seems well suited for this. Declaring a `helper_method` in the controller makes it accessible to the views.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user])
  end

  def logged_in?
    current_user != nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Before rails 4, helpers with the same controller names will be only available in their controllers and views. Starting from rails 4, all helpers are available for all controllers (if you included them) and views. With that said, all helpers will be shared across your views.

Note: if you don't want this behavior for specific controllers, you can use [`clear_helpers`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-clear_helpers), it will only include the helper with the same controller name.

For more information about using helpers see [this](https://mixandgo.com/learn/the-beginners-guide-to-rails-helpers)